# Binding and property changing between two classes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two classes that implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and independently they work as expected. However, I've added a property (Status) in one of the classes (ClassA) that gives a value based on the values in the other class (ClassB) and when a member in ClassB changes I'm not getting an update in ClassA.

Basically, ClassA has a property that holds a list of ClassBs and my idea is that when one of the members in ClassBs changes then that would reflect and update the binding for Status in ClassA.

Here's an example...

```
public class ClassA : BaseModel
{
    private ConnectionStatus _status;
    public ConnectionStatus Status
    {
        get
        {
            ConnectionStatus status = ConnectionStatus.Disconnected;

            foreach (ClassB classB in ClassBs)
            {
                status = classB.Status;

                if (status != ConnectionStatus.Connected)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return status;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ClassB> _classBs;
    public ObservableCollection<ClassB> ClassBs
    {
        get { return _classBs; }
        set
        {
            _classBs = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged("Status");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ClassB : BaseModel
{
    private ConnectionStatus _status;
    public ConnectionStatus Status
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set
        {
            _status = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

---

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ClassAObject.Status}" />
```

The Status property, when called, will reflect the correct value, but the Binding I have in XAML is not changing.

The DataContext and Binding is setup properly and it will update if I update Status manually, but not when a member in ClassBs is updated.

Comment: Seems like all you need is a third class that holds the static information.

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged("Status")` is missing. Currently assignment like `ClassBs = new ...` will work but if you change something in collection without creating a new one - you are in troubles. You can subscribe to [CollectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) event to rise notification for `Status`.

Comment: @Sinatr Perhaps what I suggested would be the easier route.

Comment: @kristech, `Status` value depends on items in collection (look at OP code). Not sure what problem your answer is solving.

Answer (score 1):

Observable collection already implements INotifyPropertyChanged so you do not need call OnPropertyChanged inside the property ClassBs

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ObservableCollection<T> : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>, System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
```

The main reason why you dont get notification when the status property in class B changed is because the property in ClassA called ClassBs is a collection of objects of type ClassB, and the object itselft does not change, only change a property inside one element inside it, but the collection is the same. For that reason, the only way to throw the notification is adding or deleting and item inside the collection.

```
private ObservableCollection<ClassB> _classBs;
    public ObservableCollection<ClassB> ClassBs
    {
        get { return _classBs; }
        set
        {
            _classBs = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged("Status");
        }
    }
```

I suggest that you create a EventHandler inside ClassB and suscribe from ClassA